# Can't include Review to the User Profile using Node js(express) and MongoDB(mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem with including review for a user. Once I create a review for a user, it displays only id, but not text or author or any other property. Will be glad to hear any thought.

Here are my schemas and routes:

1) USER SCHEMA:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");



//SCHEMA SETTING UP

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  username: String,

  password: String,

  isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false},

  firstName: String,

  lastName: String,

  email: String,

  avatar: String,

  yearOfBirth: Number,

  job: String,

  experience: Number,

  city: String,

  country: String,

  description: String,

   reviews: [

       {

        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,

        ref: "Review"

       }

    ]

});



UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);



module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

2) REVIEW SCHEMA

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Review", reviewSchema);
```

3) REVIEW ROUTE

```
    var express    = require("express");
var router     = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var Post       = require("../models/post");
var Comment    = require("../models/comment");
var User       = require("../models/user");
var Review     = require("../models/review");
var middleware = require("../middleware");

//Review New
router.get("/new",  middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // find campground by id
    console.log(req.params.id);
    User.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews").exec(function (err, user) {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.render("reviews/new", {user: user});
      }
    });
  });

//Review Create
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req, res){
   //lookup user using ID
   User.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews").exec(function (err, user) {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
           res.redirect("/users");
       } else {
        Review.create(req.body.review, function(err, review){
           if(err){
             req.flash("error", "Something went wrong :(");
               console.log(err);
           } else {
               //add username and id to comment
               review.author.id = req.user._id;
               review.author.username = req.user.username;
               //save comment
               review.save();
               user.reviews.push(review);
               user.save();
               console.log(review);
               req.flash("success", "Successfully added review!");
               res.redirect('/users/' + user._id);
           }
        });
       }
   });
});



module.exports = router;
```

4)SHOW PAGE

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

<div class="card">

  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

    <li class="list-group-item heading-user"><%=user.firstName%> <%=user.lastName%></li>

  </ul>

</div>



<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4">

    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="<%= user.avatar %>" alt="User Profile Picture">

    <div class="card">

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

        <li class="list-group-item">Profession: <%=user.job%></li>

        <li class="list-group-item">Experience: <%=user.experience%> years</li>

        <li class="list-group-item">Birth Date: <%=user.yearOfBirth%></li>

        <li class="list-group-item">Location: <%=user.country%>, <%=user.city%></li>

        <li class="list-group-item"><%=user.firstName%> has <i class="fas fa-clock"></i> 12 hours on account</li>

      </ul>

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Connect <%=user.firstName%></a>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">

    <div class="card">

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

        <li class="list-group-item">

          <p>About <%=user.firstName%>: </p>

          <p><%= user.description %></p>

        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item">Some posts of <%= user.firstName %>:

          <ul>

            <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

              <li><a href="/posts/<%= post._id %>"><%= post.title %></a></li>

            <% }); %>

          </ul>

        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>

        <div class="card bg-light comments">

            <div class="card-block">

              <a href="/users/<%=user._id%>/reviews/new" class="btn btn-inline btn-outline-secondary">What do you think about <%=user.firstName%></a>

            </div>



            <hr>

                <% user.reviews.forEach(function(review){ %>

                  <p><%= review %></p>

                <% }); %>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>



<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

In this case review is shown like an id only, but in mongo db.reviews.find() --> all ok:
https://gyazo.com/f1f476b87e554b689a36d07844ecc9b5

If I place in show page something like <%=review.author.username%> it displays me error:

> Cannot read property 'username' of undefined    at eval (eval at
>   compile (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12),
>   :114:40)    at Array.forEach ()    at eval (eval
>   at compile (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12),
>   :111:21)    at returnedFn (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)    at
>   tryHandleCache (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)    at
>   View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)    at
>   View.render (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)    at
>   tryRender (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
>   at Function.render (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
>   at ServerResponse.render (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
>   at D:\My projects\Backend\timeMe\routes\users.js:32:11    at D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4465:16
>   at (anonymous function).call (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:3613:7)
>   at process.nextTick (D:\My
>   projects\Backend\timeMe\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:35:39)
>   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)    at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Thank you for any help. Really all day in this code, can't understand what is wrong here

Comment: your user schema and review schema both are same??? i think you forgot to copy review schema???

Comment: Sure not :) Thanks for pointing on the typo

Comment: no problem :)  check the answer, you need to use populate to get referenced data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to populate the reviews field to get all the data of reviews while getting user.

```
//Review New

router.get("/new",  middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){

    // find campground by id

    console.log(req.params.id);



 User.findById(req.params.id).populate('reviews').exec( function(err, user)

     { 

        if(err){

            console.log(err);

        } else {

             res.render("reviews/new", {user: user});

        }

    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, but error still the same :(

Comment: https://gyazo.com/cd3e845a3e0262aabc8f251399486ea1
Same just ID for review and if I try to execute something like 
<% user.reviews.forEach(function(review){ %>
                  <p><%= review.author.username %></p>
                <% }); %> 
I'm getting error:
Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: Is the Author username in the Reviews schema redundant to the username in the Users schema? I think you should just reference User like this:
author: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'  }  Then be sure to populate reviews as indicated above and reference the field with review.author.username

Comment: Michael, you are right. It really doesn't change code much, but make it more clear. I populate reviews, but still got the same mistake. I rewrite this code for a million times, still no idea what the problem here...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the user "show" route.
I just needed to populate "reviews", but in user route:
//Show User

```
router.get("/:id", function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews").exec(function(err, foundUser) {
    if(err) {
      req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
      return res.redirect("/");
    }
    console.log(foundUser);
    Post.find().where('author.id').equals(foundUser._id).exec(function(err, posts) {
      if(err) {
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
        return res.redirect("/");
      }
      res.render("users/show", {user: foundUser, posts: posts});
    })
  });
});﻿
```